# c# parameters change when calling method

Tags: c#, parameters

Can someone help me with why the values of my parameters might be changing when calling my method?

I have a forms project that references a dll that can post data into Sage. I pass some parameters to the dll like this:

```
Sage200InvoiceExport.InvoiceExportMain invoice = new 
Sage200InvoiceExport.InvoiceExportMain();
invoice.INSTRUMENT_NO = varInvoiceNumber;
invoice.SECOND_REFERENCE_NO = varSecondReference;
invoice.SUPPLIER_ID = varSupplierId;
invoice.SAGE_ID = varSageID;
invoice.TRANSACTION_DATE = varDateConverted;
invoice.NET_VALUE = dnumNet;
invoice.NET_0 = dnumNet0;
invoice.NET_STD = dnumNetStd;
invoice.NET_DISC = dnumNetDisc;
invoice.VAT = dnumVAT;
invoice.PART_INVOICE = numPartInvoice;
invoice.INVOICE_TYPE = varInvoiceType;
invoice.COMPANY_ID = ACBUid;
invoice.NOMINAL = numNominal;
invoice.COST_CENTRE = numCostCentre;
invoice.INVOICE_ID = numId;
invoice.ALLOWABLE_DIFF = allowableDiff;
invoice.Execute();
```

The values of the parameters are used throughout a whole load of code and across several different methods. They are fine until I call this method:

[image showing method that changes parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71gel.png)

In the screenshot above the values are set correct. As soon as I F11 to move into the method the values get changed even though no code is seemingly executed.

[image showing changed values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kah1z.png)

You can see the values that have changed in the watched window highlighted in red.

I've checked the code against a known working version and there is nothing different. I'm struggling to think what could change the values between those two lines of code?

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Richard

Comment: Please show the entire signature of the called method.  Don't use images to show code, paste the code into the question.

Comment: Sorry Chris, new to stackoverflow, will do better next time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible that you have changed the places of the two variables NET_DISC and VAT in the call to the method?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, yes it is possible and was the case, I honestly didn't realise this was even an issue, I thought they were named and position wouldn't matter, thank you for your help

Comment: Glad to help, can you mark the answer as accepted and correct your vote (if you downvoted) if that is possible?

Comment: I didn't downvote, I have tried to upvote but I have less that 15 reputation apparently. I've marked as accepted. :-)